# Setting breakpoints in viewmodels in Durandal

Tags: requirejs, durandal

How do I use Google Chrome's (F12) feature to set breakpoints in Durandal's viewmodels?

Comment: Also, consider disabling cache in the developer tool window (use the gear icon at the bottom-right of the window) - otherwise, the require'd modules may get cached unexpectedly and your changes won't show up.  You can set require.config to include a "cache-buster" param, but that messes with (clears) your breakpoints, because Chrome debugger thinks the file is new each time it is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load the page you want to debug
2. Hit F12 in Chrome
3. click on the 'Sources' tab
4. In the pane on the left you should be able to see all your different view model js files
5. Choose one of the js files by clicking on it
6. Set a breakpoint by clicking on the code line number in the source code view
7. You can refresh the browser page and your breakpoints will remain intact