# Simple Javascript not working in my spa app

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, durandal

I am using the Hot Towel template by John Papa.  I have a html view called nav.html, which contains the header portion of my spa. Within that, i need to display the name of the person that is logged into the system (i have a server side utility class that handles the query).
The following is from the html in the nav.html view for that-
data-bind="text: LoggedInAs"

Here is the viewmodel code (nav.js)-

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Nav View'
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log('Nav View Activated', null, 'Nav', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

My problem is that i am not sure how to do this.  i tried adding nav.js to my viewmodels folder, but the javascript does not run.  I thought durandal would have picked it up like the other viewmodels.  The only difference between the nav.js and the other view models is that the other view models are triggered by clicking on a link (wired through route.mapnav).

What am i missing here?  How do i get the javascript to run without a user clicking on a link?  When the page loads, I need nav.js to run in order to populate the LoggedInAs data-bind.

Comment: Did you include the nav-view in your shell? It will not be loaded if it's not part of the page.

Comment: Ken- I did-    <header>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
    </header>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are activating your nav view. In the example code you have given in the comment above, it would need to be this:

```
<header> <!--ko compose: {view: 'nav', activate: true} --><!--/ko--> </header>
```

Comment: activate: true was missing.  It still does not hit the nav.js. So, I think you solved part of the problem, just one more piece missing. Ideas?  Also, i get 'no symbols have been loaded' when i try to set the breakpoints in the nav.js.  Thanks!

Comment: Only thing I can think of now is that the vm is not being located properly. I prefer to locate the view and view models together in the same folder, maybe try that?
Also, I highly recommend using Chrome Developer tools for debugging javascript instead of VS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789025/setting-breakpoints-in-viewmodels-in-durandal/15792756#15792756